# Adding partial data with Entity Framework AddRange

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do something without having to write a loop statement (which, given the size of the data I am dealing with, would seriously hinder performance).

I have a restful API that's receiving data from a post (written in ASP.NET Core with C#). It takes the data as a list object and tries to add a list object to the entity using `AddRange()`.

Here's the code:

```
    public void InsertBulkVehicle(List<Vehicle> rcs)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Db_LiveContext context = new Db_LiveContext())
            {
                context.VehicleLocation.AddRange(rcs);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Capture error code.
        }
    }
```

One of the problems I am having is there may be a duplicate in the list, causing a failure when I try to invoke the `SaveChanges()` command. There may be cases where I could get a large number of records back that need to be added but a couple of those records are duplicates. Is there a way to get it to ignore the duplicates and add everything else without having to iterate through the list and remove duplicates before trying to add them?

Comment: Why do you think `AddRange` isn't using a loop, and that your own loop would be slower?

Comment: I've timed it using a simple for loop (looping through and using add() for each record and not addrange() for the whole list), and it's significantly slower than if I use the addrange as I do above.  I actually started using my own loop originally so that I could easily deal with duplication, but performance needs made me switch to addrange. Now I have the problem if there are partial duplicates, the addrange fails..

Comment: The [documentation for `AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbSet_AddRange_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) states that it only calls `DetectChanges` once. Perhaps you could manually call `DetectChanges` before your loop and then turn off `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` while in your loop?

Comment: I think the best you could do is use `Distinct` or a custom `DistinctBy` depending on whether you have object or value duplicates.

Comment: Clarification: The duplicates is a conflict with the database records, not a case of duplicates inside the list. I may have a record that (for example) loads values 1,2,3,4,5 where all of those are recorders that don't appear in the database table except for record 3, and since 3 is in the database the whole insert fails.

Comment: Then looping and using `add` checks properly for that - and that is why it is slow. I would suggest a better fix would be to prevent an existing entity from somehow be put in `rcs`.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do that?  The api has no control over what json it receives, so the possibility of the json object containing a duplicate record is already there.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt really a way to ignore duplicates when using AddRange().

I would suggest something like this perhaps:

```
    public void InsertBulkVehicle(List<Vehicle> rcs)
    {
         try
         {
             using (var context = new Db_LiveContext())
             {
                 // Assuming VehicleId is the primaryKey
                 var rcsIds = rcs.Select(x => x.VehicleId).ToList();

                 var vehiclesInDb = context.VehicleLocation
                                           .Where(x => rcsIds.Contains(x.VehicleId))
                                           .ToList();

                 var vehiclesNotInDb = rcs.Where(x => !vehiclesInDb.Contains(x.VehicleId));

                 context.VehicleLocation.AddRange(vehiclesNotInDb);
                 context.SaveChanges();
             }

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
                // Capture error code.
         }

     }
```

Comment: In general, you should use `ToHashSet` instead of `ToList` when creating an object primarily intended for `Contains` checking.

Comment: The json I am getting doesn't have a single field I can use as a primary key.  I have to use two fields, one is a datetime and the other is a string in order to determine record uniqueness.

Comment: humm. In that case, You could use a Dictionary on that first Select() statement I have above. Something like this: `var test = rcs.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Status);` Then you would just need to modify the rest of the code (specifically the Where() clauses)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is impossible to skip the invalid entities. I would personally do this.

1. I first try to do an AddRange,
2. Then handle an exception, that when it fails to add a batch, do one by one.
   At least this way, you can balance it out.

   ```
    try { 

    await context.entities.AddRange(batch); 
    await context.Save(); 

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
   await SaveEntities(batch); 
   }

     //Method to add one by one 
    public void SaveEntities(List<Entity> entities) 
    { 
    foreach(var item in entities)
    { 
    // add one by one. 
    } 
    }
   ```