# How to avoid adding duplicate data from CSV file to SQL Server database. Using CSVHelper and C# Blazor

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, duplicates, blazor, csvhelper

I have my database table named 'JobInfos' in SQL Server which contains many columns.

JobID - (int) auto populates incrementing value when data added
OrgCode - (string)
OrderNumber - (int)
WorkOrder - (int)
Customer - (string)
BaseModelItem - (string)
OrdQty - (int)
PromiseDate - (string)
LineType -(string)

This table gets written to many times a day using a Blazor application with Entity Framework and CSVHelper.  This works perfectly.  All rows from the CSV file are added to the database.

```
if (fileExist)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@path))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvRow>().Select(row => new JobInfo()
                {
                    OrgCode = row.OrgCode,
                    OrderNumber = row.OrderNumber,
                    WorkOrder = row.WorkOrder,
                    Customer = row.Customer,
                    BaseModelItem = row.BaseModelItem,
                    OrdQty = row.OrdQty,
                    PromiseDate = row.PromiseDate,
                    LineType = row.LineType,
                });

        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
           while (!reader.EndOfStream)
               {
                   if (lineNumber != 0)
                   {
                       db.AddRange(records.ToList());
                       db.SaveChanges();
                   }

                   lineNumber++;
               }

               NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true);
        }

    }
```

As these multiple CSV files can contain rows that may already be in the database table, I am getting duplicate records when the table is read from, which causes the users to delete all the newer duplicate rows manually to only keep the original entry.

I have no control over the CSV files or their creation.  I am trying to only add rows that contain new data based on the WorkOrder number which can not be the same as any others.

I found another post here on StackOverflow which helps but I am stuck with a remaining error I can't figure out.

[The Helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585192/adding-partial-data-with-entity-framework-addrange)

I changed my code here...

```
if (lineNumber != 0)
    {
        var recordworkorder = records.Select(x => x.WorkOrder).ToList();

        var workordersindb = db.JobInfos.Where(x =>  recordworkorder.Contains(x.WorkOrder)).ToList();

        var workordersNotindb = records.Where(x => !workordersindb.Contains(x.WorkOrder));

        db.AddRange(records.ToList(workordersNotindb));

        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

but this line...

```
var workordersNotindb = records.Where(x => !workordersindb.Contains(x.WorkOrder));`
```

throws an error at the end (x.WorkOrder) - CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'DepotQ4.Data.JobInfo'

WorkOrder is an int
JobID is the Primary Key and an int
Every record in the table must have a unique WorkOrder

I am not sure what I am not seeing.  Could use some help here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `workordersindb` is a `List<JobInfo>`.  So when you try to select from `records.Where(x => !workordersindb.Contains(x.WorkOrder))` you are trying to match the list of `JobInfo` in `workordersindb` to the `int` of `x.WorkOrder`.  `workordersindb` needs to be a `List<int>` in order to be able to use it with the `Contains`.  `records` would have had the same issue, but you solved it by creating the variable `recordworkorder` and using `records.Select(x => x.WorkOrder)` to get a `List<int>`.

```cs
if (lineNumber != 0)
{
    var recordworkorder = records.Select(x => x.WorkOrder).ToList();

    var workordersindb = db.JobInfos.Where(x =>  recordworkorder.Contains(x.WorkOrder)).Select(x => x.WorkOrder).ToList();

    var workordersNotindb = records.Where(x => !workordersindb.Contains(x.WorkOrder));

    db.JobInfos.AddRange(workordersNotindb);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```